# Can we able to do Transformation in Druid

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, druid, pydruid

I am having a scenario where I will be receiving data in csv files and there I need to generate some columns with the existing one.
Example:

```
Col_1   Col_2    Col_3   Col_4
abc     1        No      123
xyz     2        Yes     123
def     1        Yes     345
```

Expected:

```
Col_1    Col_2    Col_3   Col_4   Col_5   Col_6
abc      1        No      123     1       1
xyz      2        Yes     123     0       0
def      1        Yes     345     0       0
```

Col_5 Condition : if Col_1 = 'abc' then 1 else 0  end
Col_6 Condition : max(Col_5) over (Col_2)

I know we can perform transformations in Druid when we loading the file in it, I tried simpler condition which is working fine for me, but I am Pretty doubt to perform aggregate and other transformation like Col_6 here.

Also we need to perform aggregate on different files data which we going to receive, Assume we get 2 file today and we loaded the data to Druid table, Tomorrow again we got some 3 files which is having data for same (ID) which is Col_2 here then we need to do aggregation based on all the records we have, Example : Col_6 generation here...

Shall this will be possible in Druid?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html
which contains many transform expressions you can use.

In particular, I tested your use case with the wikipedia demo data by creating the following expressions:

```
    {
            "type": "expression",
            "name": "isNB",
            "expression": "case_simple(\"namespace\", 'Main',1,0)"
          },

          {
            "type": "expression",
            "expression": "greatest( case_simple(\"IsNew\", True, 1, 0), case_simple(\"namespace\", 'Main',1,0)",
            "name": "combined_calc"
          }
```

One thing to note is that transform expressions cannot refer to other transform expressions, so calculations need to all be done from the raw input fields.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but how we handling Over clause here?
Also as you mentioned we transform expressions cannot refer to another transform expression, so if we using one of the transformed column to create another column, we need to use the whole condition to create new column instead of using just column name?

Comment: My bad. I misinterpreted max (col_2, col_5) hence the use of greatest function. You mean `MAX(col5) over ( PARTITION BY col_2)` which poses a different challenge, particularly across batches. You may want to experiment with this extension: https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.22.0/development/extensions-contrib/moving-average-query.html

Answer (score 0):

**Col_5 Condition : if Col_1 = 'abc' then 1 else 0**

You can use the following

```py
df = df.withColumn('Col_5', f.when((f.col('Col_1') == 'abc'), 1).otherwise(0))
```

**Col_6 Condition : max(Col_5) over (Col_2)**

You can apply window operation

```py
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Col_2").orderBy("Col_5").desc()

df_max = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(windowSpec)).filter(
    f.col("row_number") == 1
)
```

Now remove duplicates for each `Col_2` and then join the `df_max` with your main df.

The above code snippet is in python, but spark API is the same so you can use it with minimal changes.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, but I have performed all the above transformation in Spark Scala already, but now i need to do the same in **Druid** itself.
We need to eliminate Spark Scala/python from In between.

Answer (score 0):

The first type,`if Col_1 = 'abc' then 1 else 0`, would not be hard.  Eg, see [this article](https://support.imply.io/hc/en-us/articles/360050874193-Sample-ingestion-snippet-transformSpec-if-then-else-and-like-) with similar examples.

The second, aggregating over one of the columns, doesn't sound possible.  We can aggregate over all the dimensions taken together (like a primary key), but not over one single dimension, afaik.